# Как правильно записать в коде async/await javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

я начинающий разработчик на JavaScript и начал изучат обещания, и меня интересует как правильно использовать в коде async/await. Как записывать обычные Promise я знаю, а как работать async/await пока плохо понимаю, вот мой код, который не работает, помогите пожалуйста, как правильно записать код чтоб он работал.

```
let sum=(a,b)=>{
 return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     const rez=a+b
     if(rez===10){
       resolve(rez)
     } else{
       reject(new Error(`No number ${rez}`))  
     }
 }
 )}

 let rez2=async function(){
     const re=await sum(5,5)
 }
 console.log(rez2())
```

Так код работает нормально

```
let sum=(a,b)=>{
 return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     const rez=a+b
     if(rez===10){
       resolve(rez)
     } else{
       reject(new Error(`No number ${rez}`))  
     }
 }
 )}

sum(5, 9).then(re=>console.log(re)).
  catch(err=>console.log(err.message))
```

Comment: Даже если бы он работал, все равно бы ничего не вывел, там `return` нет. И получить результат асинхронной функции, можно только из асинхронной функции. Добавь в конце `rez2(...) -> return re`. А вместо простого вызова `console.log`, вызови ее так `(async () => { console.log(await rez2()) })()`

Comment: Если вам не сложно, приведите пример кода, так я лучше пойму что я не так сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(с)... не сложно

```js
let sum = (a, b) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const rez = a + b;
    (rez === 10) ? resolve(rez) : reject(new Error(`No number ${rez}`))
  })
}

async function rez2(a, b) {
  // а тут можно поймать ошибку
  try {
    return await sum(a, b)
  } catch (err) {
    return err.message
  }
}

console.log(rez2(5, 5));
// Promise { pending }

(async () => {
  console.log(await rez2(5, 5))
})();
// 10

(async () => {
  console.log(await rez2(1, 1))
})()
// No number 2
```

Comment: Если  в sum поменять значения будет ошибка код все равно нормально не работает

Comment: @Грустьжизни ... добавил

Comment: одинаково ( https://jsbin.com/pubodafuvo/edit?js,console

Comment: @Грустьжизни я не знаю, как можно скопипастить код и добавить в него ошибку. Самая же первая строка `llet` -> `let`

Comment: Вот и правильный копипаст все равно ошибка https://jsbin.com/susoqudure/edit?js,console

Comment: @Грустьжизни нет там никакой ошибки, там "Possibly"->"Возможно". При ошибке, код бы и прервался на этой строке. Причиной тому является, отсутствие блока `try/catch` в двух самых последних вызовах. Забей на этот "jsbin.com", поставь нормальный редактор(+node+eslint+nodemon) и запускай код в консоли.